# Spark Structured Streaming source retention policy

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Consider a continuous flow of JSON data on a Kafka topic, we want to deal with it by structured streaming like this:

```scala
val df = spark
   .readStream
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
   .option("subscribe", "topic1")
   .load()
```

I was wondering if the program runs for a long run, then `df` variable will become so big - in my case like 100 TB for a week. So is there any configuration available to eliminate earlier data in `df` or simply dequeue earliest rows?

Comment: Read about watermarks

Answer (score -1):

In Spark the execution will not start until an action is triggered.
This concept is called [Lazy Evaluation in Apache Spark](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/). 
“Transformations are lazy in nature meaning when we call some operation in RDD, it does not execute immediately”

Having said that the load operation is a transformation and no data will be read upon executing this line of code.

In order to kick off a streaming job to need to provide the following 4 logical components and call start:

1. The input (Kafka, file, socket, ..)
2. The trigger (how often to input get updated)
3. The result table (that is created upon a query after the tigger update)
4. Output (define what part of the result will be written)

The memory consumption depends on what is done in the query that will be triggered. [Spark Documentation:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-event-time-and-late-data):

> "Since Spark is updating the Result Table, it has full control over
>   updating old aggregates when there is late data, as well as cleaning
>   up old aggregates to limit the size of intermediate state data. Since
>   Spark 2.1, we have support for watermarking which allows the user to
>   specify the threshold of late data, and allows the engine to
>   accordingly clean up old state."

So you have to determine the amount of data needed to calculate the result table in order to estimate the about of required memory.
It is possible that an executor will crash with an OOM exception, if you do something like:  mapGroupWithState, …

Comment: Totally Unrelated. where is that configuration that OP asked for?